# Check multiple OR operators in IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following C++ code:

```
if(x==y||m==n){
cout<<"Your message"<<endl;
}
```

If x is equal to y or m is equal to n, the program prints "Your message". But if both conditions are true,the program tests only one of them and eventually prints one "Your Message".

Is there a way to print each `"Your message"` independently based on each condition using a single if statement?

The output would be identical to the below using multiple if statements.

```
if(x==y){
cout<<"Your message"<<endl;
}

if (m==n){
cout<<"Your message"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. So wil I need to use loops maybe?

Comment: Sounds like an && is what you want..

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of that. But I need the program to print the message even if only one of the conditions is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that I'd ever do it this way, but ...

```
for(int i = 0; i < (x==y)+(m==n); ++i) {
  std::cout << "Your message\n";
}
```

---

Let me expand on this. I'd never do it this way because it violates two principles:

1) Code for maintainability. This loop is going to cause the maintainer to stop, think, and try to recover your original intent. A pair of `if` statements won't.

2) Distinct input should produce distinct output. This principle benefits the user and the programmer. Few things are more frustrating than running a test, getting valid output, and **still** not knowing which path the program took.

Given these two principles, here is how I would actually code it:

```
if(x==y) {
  std::cout << "Your x-y message\n";
}
if(m==n) {
  std::cout << "Your m-n message\n";
}
```

<sup>Aside: Never use `endl` when you mean `\n`. They produce semantically identical code, but `endl` can accidentally make your program go slower.</sup>

Comment: I started to think on organizing a loop for it using arrays, but this is more elegant and effective.

Comment: Yeah, clever idea for sure! But I needed something simpler because my code is already really complex!

Comment: Not that I would use it either, but nice solution!

Comment: Complex? You would call an `else` complex? What the... ?

Comment: I doubt it can be simpler. It's just few chars more than plain if. Other solutions like separating into function/lamda will surely be larger. If you care about optimization then I think compiler will unroll the loop anyway.

Comment: No but I need to implement 10's of statements this way.

Comment: You can do another hack and do #define doubleif(c1, c2) for(int i = 0; i < (c1)+(c2); ++i)... you get the idea, but I don't understand what you are going to save, couple of chars typed? There's still more time spent here on SO than you will spend typing.

Comment: Well I'm trying to test 2d cell neighborhood with only one if.

Comment: When you say "slower" about how much do you mean. It only flushes the buffer.

Comment: A trivial test on my computer is 15x slower. I've seen it 100x slower or more.

Comment: Well, I just tested that and actually, you're right. Endl makes my program about .2 sec slower...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. What you have inside your bracket is a statement which is either true or false, there's no such thing like a true/true or true/false statement. What you could do is a do/while loop with a break statement. But I don't think that's the way to go. Why do you want to avoid two if statements?

Comment: I'm checking for 2d array value neighbors specifically and my code would be very big if I had lots of if's.

Comment: @user1981497: whoa, then every answer on this page won't help your situation.  I'd make a new question _and tell about the grid_ and how it works.  You'll get _much_ better answers.

Answer (score 1):

single "|" or "&" gaurantees both side evaluation even if the result can be determined by left side operator alone.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem ! I thought these were used only for "bit to bit" operations

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, to build up the "message":

```
string msg = "Your Message\n";
string buildSt = x == y ? m == n ? msg + msg : msg : m == n ? msg : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler checks only one condition when both are true because you've connected your conditions with OR.
If even one condition in ORs chain is true there is no need to check others as a result already true and will be false if one of them is false. So if you think that your logic is right then there is no need to do multiple checks. Your code is asking that you will print a message if one of the conditions is true and program doing it. If you want something special for a case when both conditions are true then add it separately. Shortly you should never expect from the compiler to do all checks in the expressions connected by OR.

Regards,

Davit

Comment: OK, I should then use two if's. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Tested code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    int x=1;
    int y=1;
    int m=1;
    int n=1;
    string mess1="Your message 1\n";
    string mess2="Your message 2\n";
    cout<<((x==y)?mess1:"")+((m==n)?mess2:"");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: How does this satisfy the request to print **two** copies of the message?

Comment: Why the `not` operator the same thing can be accomplished with `((x==y) && (m==n))`

Comment: Well, I've just tested that and it still shows one "Your Message" even if x=y and m=n. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Chase Walden I was mistaken about the question, but the not's where to emulate an OR statement with nands

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña: That makes more sense. No worries.

Comment: @user1981497 I just edited, sorry, was a couple of assumptions made by mistake, that code was tested in Visual Studio, it should be good to go now.

Comment: just add to 1 line if thats what you want :p
cout<<((x==y)?mess1:"")+((m==n)?mess2:"");

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to see if both statements are true an `&&` is what you will want to use.

Take a look at [Boolean Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) to see all of the possible options when comparing boolean (true/false) values.

To answer your question:

```
    if ((x==y) && (m==n))
    {
        cout<<"Your Message"<<endl<<"Your Message"<<endl;
    }
    else if((x==y) || (m==n))  
    {
        cout<<"Your Message"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Can't remove downvote until you edit, but you did fix it in the 5 minute window >.<

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm not sure. What 5 minute window?

Comment: Any edits within 5 minutes of each other by the same person all count as one edit.  So it says you have no edits, so I can't change my vote.